# WPF Window with fixed size doesnt display all contents

Tags: c#, wpf

I just started working with WPF and want to create a simple app.
However, when I place buttons at the bottom of the window and launch the app - they get cut off
Has anyone encountered this problem?

Designer preview shows this

[image: Design preview]

But then when launching the app button gets cut off

[image: App running]

XAML code is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="DXF2SVG.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DXF2SVG"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">
    <Canvas Width="400" Height="400">
        <Button x:Name="btn_LoadDXFFile" Content="Load .dxf File" Width="100" Height="40" Canvas.Top="334" Canvas.Left="150" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: set explicit size on `Canvas`, then set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` on your window ?

Comment: Thats why in WPF You dont do drag and drop, instead use XAML panels/grids and so on

Comment: Your Convas has a Height of 400 same as you window. But your Window has to Draw the buttons (Minimize, Restore, close) wihtin the same Height of 400... Which means the actual Height for the content is less than 400

Comment: Do not use a Canvas, which is meant for absolute positioning. Use a Grid or DockPanel instead. See [Panels Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview).

Comment: @vasily.sib that doesn't solve the problem. Because it's selecting the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left of the Button.

Comment: Use Grid. Canvas is evil.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I tried setting canvas width and height  to auto and that still didnt help

Comment: @SaveMyGrave that doesn't matter. Convas.Top=334+ Height=40 is more than the Visible space left for the content after the top part of the Windows is drawn

Comment: @NawedNabiZada but then why can I see it fine in preview?

Comment: Replace Canvas with a Grid. And change Convas.Top and Canvas.Left with HorizontalAligment=Center and VerticalAligment=Bottom, you will get what you want

Comment: @SaveMyGrave Because the buttons are not drawn in the preview

Comment: @NawedNabiZada great, vert/hor alignment did it, thanks!

Comment: Canvas is not at all evil. It's just not the right Panel to use for positioning a Button in a Window.

Answer (score -1):

Everyone who said canvas is evil is right
@NawedNabiZada 's answer about grid and vertical and horizontal alignment did the trick
thanks everyone!